# Auto synthesis error in AFURLRequestSerialization with Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, xcode6

How do I fix the warning "auto property synthesis will not synthesize because it is readwrite but it will be synthesized readonly via another property" for the properties streamStatus and streamError that I'm getting with the latest AFNetworking on the Xcode 6 beta?

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.m#L733

Here's the relavent line in AFURLRequestSerialization.m line 733 and 734:

```
@interface AFMultipartBodyStream () <NSCopying>
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, assign) NSStreamStatus streamStatus;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) NSError *streamError;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like the version of clang that ships with xcode 6 beta doesn't authorize to rewrite properties in an extension that is not a direct extension of the original class holding those properties.

removing:

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, assign) NSStreamStatus streamStatus;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) NSError *streamError;
```

and replacing it with :

```
@interface NSStream ()
@property (readwrite) NSStreamStatus streamStatus;
@property (readwrite, copy) NSError *streamError;
@end
```

solves the issue.

I've opened a [pull request](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/2127) in the AFNetworking repo to solve this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I JUST set up my Xcode 6 to work with developing iOS 7 apps, and it fixed an autosynthesis issue I was having with AFNetworking. I changed my build tools to `5.1` and moved the 7.1 SDK into the `Developer/SDKs` dir in `Xcode 6`. The issue (obviously) is that I need to change the build tools when working on `iOS 8` explicitly, but it's much better than switching back and forth between 5 and 6.

**Changing Build Tools**

1. Open Xcode Preferences (cmd+,)
2. Navigate to the 'Locations' tab
3. Change 'Command Line Tools' from `Xcode 6.0` to `Xcode 5.1.1`

**Getting iOS 7 SDK**

1. Open Terminal
2. Run `cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk /Applications/Xcode6-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk`
3. Restart Xcode

You should now be able to set `iOS 7.1` as your base SDK

This should solve your issue in the short term until all of these libraries are updated for `iOS 8.0` and the new build tools.

Comment: what do command line tools actually do? Do you understand that this solution is too bad?