# @property (readwrite, nonatomic, assign, getter = isCancelled) BOOL cancelled - xcode6 cause compiler error

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I've been working on xcode 5.0.2 with AFNetworking, everything worked perfectly.
when I upgraded to xcode 6 GM I got the warnining: `Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'cancelled' because it is 'readwrite' but it will be synthesized 'readonly' via another property` on this line:

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, assign, getter = isCancelled) BOOL cancelled
```

and error: `Use of undeclared identifier '_cancelled'`

```
- (void)cancel {
    [self.lock lock];
    if (![self isFinished] && ![self isCancelled]) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isCancelled"];
        _cancelled = YES; <-- THIS LINE CAUSES THE ERROR
        [super cancel];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isCancelled"];

        // Cancel the connection on the thread it runs on to prevent race conditions
        [self performSelector:@selector(cancelConnection) onThread:[[self class] networkRequestThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO modes:[self.runLoopModes allObjects]];
    }
    [self.lock unlock];
}
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083358/auto-synthesis-error-in-afurlrequestserialization-with-xcode-6) on SO and downloaded xcode 5.1.1 copied the library like suggested set the base sdk to 7.1 and the error remains

any suggestions?

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083358/auto-synthesis-error-in-afurlrequestserialization-with-xcode-6 already has answer with instructions how to manually copy sdk from xcode 5.1.

Comment: Why bother with this? If you really want to keep using Xcode 5, use Xcode 5.1 - it has iOS 7.1. But you really should start using Xcode 6 and develop for iOS 8 at this point.

Comment: @nyekimov if you read closely my question you see that I'm using xcode 5.0.2 thus i don't have xcode 5.1 to copy from the sdk -->that is why I'm asking the question

Comment: @rmaddy I've downloaded XCode 6 to start using it but have a compiler error that need to be fixed!

Comment: So fix the code. There is no need whatsoever to install a different SDK into Xcode 6.

Comment: @rmaddy please help, how to fix it

Comment: Do you have another line somewhere, perhaps in a private class extension, that redeclares that property as `readonly`?

Comment: @liva Simply add the ivar to the class.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg no the only place is in the AFURLConnectionOperation.m file

Answer (score 4):

`NSOperation` changed the read accessor names for a couple of its properties, cancelled -> isCancelled and finished -> isFinished (I think). Before they were methods, but now they are properties.

`AFNetworking` needs to be updated to a version that has the fixed synthesizing. The AFURLConnectionOperation.m file now has the following to fix this issue.

```
@synthesize cancelled = _cancelled;
```